# Get attributs from lines whith both MIN and MAX clauses on different columns

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have the following table:

[image]

for each (id_notification/no_doc) I want to have the line that has the minimum no_ligne and then the maximim dt_capt. In this case, the result would be the third line. I also need to have a column that indicates the number of lines we have for each (id_notification/no_doc). In this case it swould be 4.

What I did is a first join to have lines that have `no_ligne=min(no_ligne)` (I know that it can be easier) 
and then a second join to have lines that have `dt_capt=max(dt_capt)` but it doesn't work if the line which has a `max(dt_capt)` doesn't have a no_ligne which is equal to `min(no_ligne)`. This is what I tried:

```
select * from
(select a.id_notification, a.no_doc, b.minlignes, b.nblignes, a.dt_capt
from ${use_database}.lkr_send_editique as a
join
(select id_notification, no_doc, count(no_ligne) as nblignes, min(no_ligne) as minlignes from ${use_database}.lkr_send_editique group by id_notification, no_doc) as b
on a.id_notification=b.id_notification and a.no_doc=b.no_doc and b.minlignes=a.no_ligne) as tt

join

(select s.id_notification, s.no_doc, s.dt_capt,
s.typ_mvt from ${use_database}.lkr_send_editique as s
join
(select id_notification, no_doc, max(dt_capt) as dtmax FROM ${use_database}.lkr_send_editique group by id_notification, no_doc) as c
on s.id_notification=c.id_notification and s.no_doc=c.no_doc and s.dt_capt=c.dtmax and s.dt_capt=c.dtmax) as maxxx

on tt.id_notification=maxxx.id_notification and tt.no_doc=maxxx.no_doc and tt.dt_capt=maxxx.dt_capt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for each (id_notification/no_doc) I want to have the line that has the minimum no_ligne and then the maximim dt_capt. In this case, the result would be the third line.

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id_notification, no_doc) as cnt
             row_number() over (partition by id_notification, no_doc order by no_ligne, dt_capt desc) as seqnum
      from ${use_database}.lkr_send_editique t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @forpas, so it is. And I can't edit the comment. Maybe masking it was the problem? I can paste the address and get there, but clicking throws a 404. I'll try it again here without the display text.  On Windowing Functions in Hive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Comment: That seems to work. I'll delete the initial comment to dispose of the bad link.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can I join the table to another one? How can I do that please? I want to have also the minimum dt_capt of all lines per id_notification, no_doc.

Comment: @AbderrahmenM . . . You can use a subquery or CTE or just add a `JOIN` to `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to get the 3d row only and join to a query that returns the number of lines:

```
select t.*, tt.counter 
from tablename t inner join (
  select id_notification, no_doc, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by id_notification, no_doc 
) tt on tt.id_notification = t.id_notification and tt.no_doc = t.no_doc
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id_notification = t.id_notification and no_doc = t.no_doc
  and (no_ligne < t.no_ligne or (no_ligne = t.no_ligne and dt_capt > t.dt_capt))
)
```